# Linear isometry to the bounded linear operators space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces.

a) Construct a linear isometry $Y\rightarrow \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ in which $ \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is the set of Bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$.

b) If $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is complete, show that $Y$ is complete.

I think I have to assign to each element of $Y$, say $y$, a bounded linear operator, say $T$ that brings an element of $X$, say $x$, to $y$. However, I am not sure such operator $T$ exists or not? Any idea to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the question about part (b) and part (a)? Or (a) only? If you have an answer to (a), then you can use the reverse linear isometry $\mathcal{B}(X,Y) \to Y$ to show that completeness of $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ implies completeness of $Y$ (i.e. you can bijectively map any Cauchy sequence in $Y$ to a Cauchy seqeunce in $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$, the latter has a limit point, show that the value of the reverse isometry applied to the limit point is the limit in $Y$. Also based on your comment it seems your question is about (a), which to me also seems more difficult (idk the answer to part a myself tbh).

Comment: Your idea is fine. Define $T_yx=\varphi(x)y,$ where $\varphi(x)$ is a bounded linear functional on $X.$ Then $y\mapsto T_y$ gives a solution.

Comment: Sounds perfect. So I should define $L: Y\rightarrow \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ with $L(y)=T_y$, and then prove $L$ is an isometry, i.e., $||L(y)||=||y||$. Do you have any idea to prove $T$ is isometry? Can we define $\phi(x)$ in such a way that $||\phi||=1$?